# Postfix sender_bcc directive only on emails sent from localhost

Tags: postfix

I have Ubuntu 12.04 server with Postfix 2.9.6 configured to relay emails from external authenticated users and local/web applications. Is it possible to configure sender_bcc so it matches only emails sent from applications on server. We must have copies of all emails that are sent through web apps, but I cannot rely on From: and To: fields because some web apps are sending email on behalf of our users, and that emails should be matched by sender_bcc

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that works, but you could try making your webapps deliver to a different IP then your external users. That is, in your master.cfg you would have at least two smtpd process configured, each listening on different IPs. For the IP of the webapps, you could then add something like

```
-o sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_bcc
```

as option for the smtpd process in the master.cfg.

Comment: Unfortunately sender_bcc is not an smtpd option (http://www.postfix.org/smtpd.8.html).